# python shorten nested unmutable object variable names

Tags: python

This question is mostly just about curiosity.

As a java programmer myself, I often get frustrated by all the dots on nested variables. (There is kind of a de facto standard in java that any line with a variable with more than 2 dots needs to be re-written). Is there anyway to "rename" a nested variable such that I don't have to type all the dots everytime?

For example

```
class MyClass():
    def my_func():
        if not self.app.arguments.foo:
            self.app.arguments.foo = 'bar'
        print self.app.arguments.foo
```

Is there a way to write this such that I don't have to type the full name `self.app.arguments.foo` everytime?

Second, what is the standard 'pythonic' way of using variables as such. Would standard python nomenclature say just use all the dots all the time?

---

### Extra notes

As I said, this is more about curiosity. So lets assume that I do not have access to module b. In other words I can not (more like don't want to) write getter and setter methods.
Also note that the `self` is important. I know I can do a rename with an import, but you cant import `self`.

Comment: in my experience, you don't need such a deep nesting, and you can solve the same problem with a simpler data model. If you have a real example, we might can help you.

Comment: @Daniel I have edited my example to be more along the lines of what I am doing. self has a pointer to its parent, which has a data-structure, which contains foo (previously C).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a temporary variable for all but the last item in a chain:

```
b = self.a.b
if b.c:
    b.c = 'foo'
print b.c
```

If you weren't assigning, you could go all the way to `c`.

This is a little bit faster as well as being easier to write.  However, it may or may not be easier to *read*.

Comment: Makes sense. Oddly its so simple I am surprised I didn't think of it.